# Drag and Drop in android web view for image

Tags: android

I want to do the drag and drop operation in android web view for the images in the webpages.

Code is like this.

```
WebView webView;
ImageView imageView;
ImageView shadowImageView;

private static final String IMAGEVIEW_TAG = "icon bitmap";
public static final String TAG="ResourceSharing";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_browser);
    webView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    imageView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.downloadImage);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewController());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.picasaweb.google.com");
    webView.clearCache(true);
    webView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    shadowImageView=new ImageView(this);
    shadowImageView.setImageBitmap( BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.picasa_logo));
    shadowImageView.setTag(IMAGEVIEW_TAG);  


}
public class WebViewController extends WebViewClient {

     @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
}
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

    HitTestResult hitTestResult=webView.getHitTestResult();
    Log.i(TAG, "Hit type"+hitTestResult.getType());
    switch (hitTestResult.getType()) {
    case HitTestResult.IMAGE_TYPE:
        Log.i(TAG, "Ïnside image type");
        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
    case HitTestResult.IMAGE_ANCHOR_TYPE:
        Log.i(TAG, "Ïnside image type");
        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
    case HitTestResult.SRC_IMAGE_ANCHOR_TYPE:
        Log.i(TAG, "Ïnside image type");
        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        performDragAndDropOperation();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    return true;
}
@TargetApi(11)
private void performDragAndDropOperation(){
    ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((CharSequence) shadowImageView.getTag());
    ClipData dragData = new ClipData((CharSequence) shadowImageView.getTag(),new String[] { ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN },item);
    DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new MyDragShadowBuilder(shadowImageView);
    shadowImageView.startDrag(dragData, shadowBuilder, null, 0);
}

 private static class MyDragShadowBuilder extends View.DragShadowBuilder {
        private static Drawable shadow;
            public MyDragShadowBuilder(View v) {
                super(v);
                shadow = new ColorDrawable(Color.LTGRAY);
            }
            @Override
            public void onProvideShadowMetrics (Point size, Point touch){
                int width;
                int height;
                Log.i(TAG, "calling getVIew" +getView());
                width = getView().getWidth() / 2;
                height = getView().getHeight() / 2;
                shadow.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
                size.set(width, height);
                touch.set(width / 2, height / 2);
                Log.i(TAG, "calling getVIew" +getView());
            }
            @Override
            public void onDrawShadow(Canvas canvas) {
                Log.i(TAG, "calling getVIew" +getView());
                shadow.draw(canvas);
            }
        }
```

But when i run the application and try to drag an image after long press an error is coming in the logcat unable to initiate drag in andriod with null pointer exception.

Looking for help